# How can I use my Bluetooth speaker for 2 Apps Spotify + Microphone Apps at same time?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, microphone, speakers

I would like to play the music on my Bluetooth speaker while singing over the music played from another application such as Spotify or YouTube. (Microphone Apps can be downloaded from the Apple store and works fine with my speaker, but it cuts of Spotify Apps)  iPhone 8 iOS12.

Musixmatch does it at monthly subscription charge and requires external microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Rex.

**What will work out of the gate is to:**

1. Start something playing in the background (including Spotify).
2. Open GarageBand, and make a new project to record the microphone.
3. On the righthand side of the GarageBand window, turn on the monitor.

It will help you to go to the Advanced section of Song Settings, and switch on "Run in Background." That way the mic will be what's in the background, not your music app.

Now you'll hear your voice on top of the other audio - there might be a really big delay between when you speak/sing and when you hear it on the speaker, but this will have to do with what hardware is involved. Turning on "Send MIDI clock" *might* help, and turning off all effects on the track might as well... but better would be to try different hardware.

Either [Audiobus 3](https://audiob.us/) or [AUM](http://kymatica.com/Software/AUM) *should* do this too - neither is a free program, however, and I didn't test them.

Good luck!

---