# Can my iPad, wired mic and wireless speaker all work together simultaneously?

Tags: ipad, audio, bluetooth, microphone

I have an iPad.
I have a wired microphone with a lightning plug.
I have wireless bluetooth speakers.

Can I play a song on the iPad, sing through the mic and have the sound of the music and my voice come out through the bluetooth speaker?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  What iPad are you using and what iOS version are you running?  There's answers already provided for similar questions (like [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/338330/88313) for example).  Have you tried any of the solutions in those answers yet?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, iPadOS doesn't allow for this sort of control over audio devices and outputs. At most, you can output to multiple Airplay devices: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/421037