# Bluetooth 5, Multiple Speakers, and iPad mini 5 on iPadOS 14.5.1

Tags: ipad, audio, bluetooth, ipados

So, I am trying to pair 2 Bluetooth speakers with each other so they share the same audio. I know that starting with iOS 13 there is the "Audio Sharing" feature, but I think that is only for iPods or other devices with the W1 chip. I also believe that Bluetooth 5 equipped devices have the functionality to play to two Bluetooth speakers simultaneously.

I am using an iPad Mini 5, Updated to iPadOS 14.5.1. The iPad has Bluetooth 5 capability, which supposedly allows the connection of multiple devices of the same type. However, when I try to connect 2 Bluetooth speakers, I only get the option to toggle between them, not play audio on both. Am I doing something incorrectly, or am I mis-understanding something? If it makes a difference, I am using YouTube Music with an active premium subscription.
Thanks.

[image: Blutooth 5 Description]
[image: iPad Mini 5 has Bluetooth 5]
[image: iPad will not allow both to be connected simultaneously.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not with bluetooth but with iOS's audio out selection.

Your device is connected to both devices as both are present as options in the airplay screen as seen in your image. You can confirm this by going into bluetooth in settings and seeing that both devices are connected.

The issue you have is that iOS can only output to one device at once, with the exception of the airplay compatible devices (e.g. Apple TV, HomePod, 3rd-party airplay 2 compatible devices, etc.) or headphones/earbuds with and apple chip, either W1 or H1 (AirPods & beats).

So the only way at the moment to get multiple bluetooth speakers playing audio from your iPad is to buy one that are airplay 2 compatible.

Comment: But I thought that since Bluetooth 5 is in the iPad, that allows the iPad to Bluetooth to multiple speakers? (See the first screenshot) Thanks.

Comment: It’s important to understand the difference between “connecting” and “playing”. Your iPad can (and has) connected to both speakers. The problem is is that iOS will not play to multiple Bluetooth devices, unless they have an Apple audio chip or support AirPlay 2. Your speakers don’t have an Apple audio chip nor support airplay.

Comment: Is there a way (loophole, hack, etc.) to have it play to multiple devices? I can use multiple devices if necessary, but all of the apps that I have found mentioned here or on the app store require money, or are laggy. Thanks for the answer!